# I get this error when I try to upload a file with apollo-server using createReadStream ,

Tags: node.js, apollo-server

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at ReadStream.open (C:\Users\sofia\OneDrive\Bureau\project\backend\node_modules\apollo-server-core\node_modules\fs-capacitor\lib\index.js:80:7)
at _openReadFs (internal/fs/streams.js:138:12)
at ReadStream. (internal/fs/streams.js:131:3)
at ReadStream.deprecated [as open] (internal/util.js:89:15)
at ReadStream.open (C:\Users\sofia\OneDrive\Bureau\project\backend\node_modules\apollo-server-core\node_modules\fs-capacitor\lib\index.js:90:11)
at _openReadFs (internal/fs/streams.js:138:12)
at ReadStream. (internal/fs/streams.js:131:3)
at ReadStream.deprecated [as open] (internal/util.js:89:15)
at ReadStream.open (C:\Users\sofia\OneDrive\Bureau\project\backend\node_modules\apollo-server-core\node_modules\fs-capacitor\lib\index.js:90:11)
at _openReadFs (internal/fs/streams.js:138:12)
at ReadStream. (internal/fs/streams.js:131:3)
at ReadStream.deprecated [as open] (internal/util.js:89:15)
at ReadStream.open (C:\Users\sofia\OneDrive\Bureau\project\backend\node_modules\apollo-server-core\node_modules\fs-capacitor\lib\index.js:90:11)
at _openReadFs (internal/fs/streams.js:138:12)
at ReadStream. (internal/fs/streams.js:131:3)
at ReadStream.deprecated [as open] (internal/util.js:89:15)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOSEt.png)

Comment: is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59620803/createreadstream-throwing-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-when-up) helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an existing issue with apollo-server

You can find solutions here:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/3508

One solution is to downgrade node to 12.x

Comment: thank  you, I know this before, I just hoped there was another solution !It appears that there is no other solution until Apollo decides to fix the problem